# CoreData Custom Migration Policy - Fetch Request

Tags: ios, core-data

In Custom Migration Policy, I have to verify for duplication of "Tags".

During migration, i created entity "Tags" and associate that with its associated entity.

```
let tagEntiryDes = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Tags", in: destinationContext)

                    let newTag = Tags(entity: tagEntiryDes!, insertInto: destinationContext)
                    newTag.name = tag
```

However upon next entity creation i have to check whether the same Tags is exists or not. Using below fetch request.

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Tags")
                    let result = try destinationContext.fetch(request)
```

Here result is [Any]. Array of NSManagedObject. However while force casting this to

```
let existingTags = result as? [Tags]
```

it gives me nil value. How can i convert NSManagedObject to its subclass "Tags".